# Star Trek: Is the Post-Atomic Horror still canon?

Tags: star-trek, canon

I can't say I've seen every episode of Star Trek. I've dabbled in Enterprise, Voyager and DS9 (mainly Voyager and Enterprise). But the first episode of TNG made it fairly clear that in the past, most of the earth suffered from a nuclear war and society began to break down.

I was surprised.

Nowhere in any of the episodes I had seen — even Enterprise — was there a reference to this supposedly huge aspect of their world. You would think the Vulcans would have used it against them every chance they got, instead of just calling humans emotional, but they never mentioned, nor alluded to this aspect of humanity’s history.

So I ask, is the Post-Atomic horror still canon? Or has it been written out over time?

Comment: Enterprise follows on from First Contact. You should watch First Contact. Also the Vulcans are fine ones to talk...

Comment: If you are just starting with TNG, you have a real treat waiting for you. It's widely considered to be the best part of the Star Trek shows.

Comment: "You would think the Vulcans would have used it against them every chance they got, instead of just calling humans emotional, but they never mentioned, nor alluded to this aspect of humanity’s history." In the 4th season of Enterprise they discussed how the Vulcans went through a similar period and it took them 1500 years to recover and master warp flight, while earth did it in 100 years. This made the Vulcans very nervous about humans future impact on the galaxy.

Comment: In Enterprise they don't directly say it, but that's what the whole "too soon" thing is all about that Vulcans keep saying through out. Much of the world was still doing crazy barbaric things inside living memory, less than 100 years ago.

Comment: "I've dabbled in...mainly Voyager and Enterprise". Jesus. Rough luck.

Answer (score 28):

The [Third World War](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/World_War_III) (and its resulting nuclear exchange and [subsequent unpleasantness](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Post-atomic_horror)) has been referenced in every Trek show to date. You may wish to note that it's been described very inconsistently, mostly because the show's writers seem to be somewhat at odds over whether the [Eugenics Wars](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eugenics_Wars) should be considered to be part of World War III or something distinct.

---

### TOS

> **SPOCK:** *They do seem to have escaped the carnage of your first three world wars, Doctor.*
>
> **MCCOY:** *They have slavery, gladiatorial games, despotism.*
>
> **SPOCK:** *Situations quite familiar to the six million who died in your first world war, the eleven million who died in your second, **the
> thirty seven million who died in your third.** Shall I go on?*
>
> <sub><sup>[TOS: Bread and Circuses](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/43.htm)</sup></sub>

### TNG

> **DATA:** *According to our astrometric readings we're in the mid twenty-first century. From the radioactive isotopes in the atmosphere
> **I would estimate we have arrived approximately ten years after the
> Third World War.***
>
> **RIKER:** *Makes sense. Most of the major cities have been destroyed. There are few governments left. Six hundred million dead. No
> resistance.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Star Trek: First Contact](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/movie8.html)</sub></sup>

### DS9

> **BASHIR:** *Two years? Isn't that a bit harsh?*
>
> **BENNETT:** *I don't think so. **Two hundred years ago we tried to improve the species through DNA resequencing, and what did we get for
> our trouble? The Eugenics Wars.** For every Julian Bashir that can be
> created, there's a Khan Singh waiting in the wings. A superhuman whose
> ambition and thirst for power have been enhanced along with his
> intellect. The law against genetic engineering provides a firewall
> against such men and it's my job to keep that firewall intact. I've
> made my offer. Do you accept?*
>
> **RICHARD:** *Yes.*

<sub><sup>[Doctor Bashir, I Presume](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/514.htm)</sup></sub>

### VOY

> **DOCTOR:** *Throughout human history weapons of mass destruction were often designed in the hopes that they'd never be used.*
>
> **SEVEN:** *And yet, **in Earth's Third World War, nuclear weapons accounted for six hundred million casualties.** Were they looking on the
> bright side?*
>
> **DOCTOR:** *An unfortunate exception.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Voy: In the Flesh](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/504.htm)</sub></sup>

### ENT

> **ARCHER:** *For thousands of years, my people had similar problems. **We fought three world wars that almost destroyed us. Whole generations
> were nearly wiped out.***
>
> **KOLOS:** *What changed?*
>
> **ARCHER:** *A few courageous people began to realise they could make a difference.*
>
> <sup><sub>[ENT: Judgement](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/45.htm)</sub></sup>

and

> **JOSIAH:** *And they sat by while **millions of our people died. World War Three.***
>
> **TUCKER:** *We didn't make contact with the Vulcans until ten years after the war.*
>
> **JOSIAH:** *But they were up there with their superior technology. They could've stopped it, but they didn't. I think it suited their
> plans. A devastated Earth was much easier for them to control.*
>
> <sup><sub>[ENT: Terra Prime](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/97.htm)</sub></sup>

Comment: And the film "first contact" had the aftermath of the war as a key part of it's plot.

Comment: @PeterGreen - Yes, it was set after WWIII, in a period of relative calm.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Very Informative!

Comment: Good job finding the quotes.  However, the DS9 quote could easily reference WWII, as it just says "last world war". I like that you have said it was in all shows. But, it would help to have a DS9 quote that explicitly mentioned WWIII.

Comment: @Makyen - I was hoping no-one would notice :-) Better now?

Comment: Yes, that is better.  Although, to be logically complete, you would need a quote from one of the shows that equates The Eugenics Wars with WWIII.

Comment: @Makyen - That would be the answer to a different question. The linked Memory Alpha pages contain info about the connection between the Eugenics War and WWIII if anyone's interested in digging that deep,

Comment: Great answer, thanks :)

Comment: Hm, the current DS9 quote would indicate the Eugenics Wars took place _after_ ENT

Comment: @Izkata - I think the implication is 200 ***-ish*** years

Comment: @Valorum 300-400 years (depending on late 2000s or late 1990s) isn't an "ish"

Comment: @Izkata - He's a doctor, dammit, not a historian.

Comment: I'm uncertain of the canonicity, but the [_The Eugenics Wars_ books](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Eugenics_Wars) are set during the Eugenics Wars and follow the exploits of two agents trying to prevent Khan from inciting WWIII. The climactic scene of the second book takes place sometime in the 1990s and features American bombers and Russian commandos coming to attack Khan's base in India, implying that the geopolitical landscape is more-or-less the same as it was at that period in real history, and that WWIII happened at some point further down the line.

Comment: A few notes - The Eugenics War is happening during the period that Voyager visited in the 90s. There are a few subtle hints at this. And the Bell Riots are likely the result of the Eugenics War that was happening around the same time. WWIII happens 20 to 30 years later and is likely prompted by so many disposessed from the Eugenics War, much like how WW2 is the result of WW1, but because there are so many people and it wasn't a WW there was a much greater delay between the 2 wars in WW3's case.

Comment: @Durakken - What "subtle hints" were there in Future's End?

Comment: @Valorum It has been a while since I've seen it but I know there is the model of the Botany Bay on the desk of the dude which means it was built before then and then there is arguments surrounding that. I think there is also some talk about conflict that is going on in China and India, but I'm not sure. Perhaps there is another question that is similar to "Why are there no signs of the Eugenics War in Future's End even though it's supposed to be happening at that time?" that you can get answers from.

Comment: @Durakken - I'll have a hunt and a rewatch of the episodes. If I don't find anything, I'll post it as a question.

Comment: @Valorum The Eugenics War is one of those things that canon isn't real clear about. Some people think it is another name for WW3, some say it's separate but happens later than the stated 90s of TOS. Others say it happens in the 90s like TOS says. The Botany Bay model, if I remember right, is supposed to be an easter egg that the runners put in there so they recognized it was supposed to be there, but not sure thats enough to really argue they were making a statement with regard to the facts of the timeline.

Comment: @Valorum - So how many actually died in WWIII? 37M (Spock) or 600M (Riker/Seven)?

Comment: @iMerchant Considering Spock's figures for the first two world are blatantly inaccurate (he claims 7 and 11 million; real numbers, 38 and 60 million), I'd definitely be more inclined to believe Riker and Seven.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - It makes me wonder if this is the only time Spock has been wrong on the show. I suppose that could be a new question.

Comment: @iMerchant - I suppose it depends on how you look at it, and what you consider to be a directly resulting death. For example, you could look at the [Hundred Years War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hundred_Years%27_War) was as *a single discrete conflict* or a series of battles. The death count for the ***entire conflict*** was 3.5m, but the [decisive battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Castillon) only resulted in some 4000 deaths. Spock might only be referring to the initial nuclear exchange rather than the aftermath.

Answer (score 2):

The Post-Atomic Horror takes place between 2053 and 2123.
What you are mistaking is that you assume that as soon as the Vulcans make contact that just ends all of the problems. This is not the case. In First Contact we are seeing the Early years of the Post-Atomic Horror and we're only dealing with one faction of humans that are still fairly civilized in 2063.

By 2079 an attempt at a New United Nations failed. Obviously a number of factions gained enough power to form countries and have global talks, which indicates that a number of nations were recovering quite quickly, probably with the aid of the Vulcans, but there likely was a resource disparity which lead to rich nations fairing pretty well, but poor nations falling into what we see presented by Q.

By the 2100s Europe was reforming and uplifting the poorer communities, eventually forming the European Hegemony in 2123. Between this period and 2151, the United Earth Government formed and all governments by 2151 joined. 2151 is also when the NX-01 launched.

So the Post-Atomic Horror that TNG made famous with those Q episodes takes place 16 years AFTER First Contact and in areas of the world we generally don't look at in Star Trek. Most likely in Eastern Europe, Africa, and Asia.

A more full run down can be found [Here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Post-atomic_horror)

There is also a episode in TOS that likely inspired the idea of the Post-Atomic Horror called the Omega Glory. You could think of it as a "what if the Vulcans never made first contact."

Answer (score 0):

The Eugenics Wars took place in the 1990s and were a separate conflict lasting through the early 21st century. They were secret wars and not known as the Eugenics Wars until long afterwards.

World War Three was fought in 2053. Asia appeared to have suffered the most damage although several cities in North America and Europe were destroyed, and living conditions were worse than they had been since the Great Depression (First Contact), although based on a photograph of one of Captain Janeway's ancestors in Voyager, the impact was apparently less severe in some places. Most of the Post Atomic Horror (including the mutants and monsters that appeared afterward) seems to have happened in Asia (which might also explain why there are so few Asians in Star Trek overall). According to Picard, the world had been able to recover "within a generation" (First Contact) after meeting the Vulcans.